# Types of props are incompatible between these types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

There is a component with a `items` property and items will receive an array of ItemProps.
why I'm getting blow error:

```
Type '{ label: string; icon: string; badge: { type: string; }; } | { label: string; icon: string; badge?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ItemProps'.
Type '{ label: string; icon: string; badge: { type: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ItemProps'.
The types of 'badge.type' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"indicator" | "info" | undefined'.
```

Source:

```js
import React from "react"

export interface BadgeProps {
  type?: "indicator" | "info"
}

export interface ItemProps {
  label?: string,
  icon?: string
  disabled?: boolean
  badge?: BadgeProps
}

export interface ItemsProps {
  items: ItemProps[]
}

const Items: React.FunctionComponent<ItemsProps> = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { String(items) }
    </div>
  )
}

const Test: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  
  const items = [
    {
      label: "Home",
      icon: "MdHome",
      badge: {
        type: "indicator"
      }
    },
    {
      label: "Profile",
      icon: "MdPerson"
    },
    {
      label: "Settings",
      icon: "MdSettings"
    }
  ]

  return (
    <Items items={items}/>
  )
}

export default Test
```

Comment: In my opinion, typescript doesn't understand the type of items array. If you pass a type to items: like 

const items: ItemsProps = [
 ...the rest, the issue should be gone. 
]

Comment: @TigranPetrosyan thanks for your response. Yeah this will resolve the problem but I rather not to announce type directly, because other developers should be able to use the component without need to import ItemProps type.

Comment: Use `as const`: https://tsplay.dev/wOxaMN

Comment: @TobiasS. Thanks, seems it's working as expected